# How to load a DLL as a local server

Tags: c++, com, dll

I really need help...

I have implemented a COM component (i.e A.dll) with IDL, also coded a wrapper DLL (B.dll) for that component. I have implemented required export functions for DLL "A" and registered it with "regsvr32.exe".

Problem is that I have 3 EXE files that uses B.dll to access methods of A.dll. But, I could not manage to create a local server for A.dll, therefore every EXE loads a new A.dll and B.dll. I want to load A.dll only once, and need to realize this functionality in B.dll. Last statement is open for discussion also.

However, I could not manage to find any useful example or resource regarding this problem. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you oppose to having those libraries loaded several times?

Comment: @sharptooth since, A.dll opens a database file as a resource, and opening this file more than once causes problems.

Comment: I see. I guess the better solution would be to use an NT service for dealing with the database. This way you don't care of how many copies of the COM server you have at once - they will talk to the service via say RPC and the service will synchronize access to the database internally.

Comment: Why could you not create a local server for A.dll? Create a stub.exe file, register it as the LocalServer32 key. Get it to RegisterClassObject the A.DLL file. And youre good to go (Assuming you used IDL to define everything so you have the proxy stub dlls).

Comment: lol. I added this as a comment not a reply because your post indicated you already tried and failed at this approach.

Comment: @Chris Becke: That's a way to go, but more often you can just put your in-proc server into COM+ and have an out-proc server for free.

Comment: You could try using a DLL surrogate (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695225.aspx).

Comment: @Chris the problem was the proxy stub dll. Your comment helped to identify it. Also, localserver32 registration and implementation was incorrect. Also, in this link you can find a good resource: http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2007/04/08/the-ancient-art-of-circles-and-lollipops-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DLL mediated by COM is known as an in-process server.  Which suggests your problem: it will always be mapped into the memory space of its clients, just like any other DLL.  Similarly any DLLs *it* loads will be mapped into the original process.  It is not clear from your question *why* you don't want to use a DLL.  If it is to save resources then consider that only data will be duplicated; the code will only be loaded once.  If it is because you want them to share data, then consider using shared memory.  If you really want all three .exe's to be served by an instance then what you need is a COM local server, which will be implemented by an .exe, not a .dll.

Comment: Or use a surrogate executable for the DLL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686606(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "create a local server". In-proc server has to be loaded into each consumer process, there's no way around that - each consumer is a separate process, so it has its own copy of code and data.

In order to have a single process executing COM server code for all of the consumers you have to create an out-proc server. To do the latter you can either reengineer your COM server or try to use COM+ server application. This way you can have a separate process running the COM server code several consumers can connect to.